# Unable to instantiate class in 2 different Class library projects

Tags: c#, class, oop, namespaces

i have created 2  Class  library projects in one solution , named  `Fundamentls` and `Fundamentals.test` inside Fundamentls  i have  class Greeter

```
namespace Fundamentals
{
    public  class Greeter
    {
        public string SayHello() 
        {
            return "Hello" ;
        }
    }
}
```

now when in  `Fundamentals.test` i try to do this

```
using Fundamentals; 
namespace Fundamentals.Test
{ 
    [TestFixture]
    public class GreeterTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void SayHelloReturnsHello() 
        {
            Greeter g = new Greeter();
        }
    }
}
```

now this is what i get

[image]

i have  build the project after adding namespace but still does not work ,

Comment: Have you added a reference to the `Fundamentals` project in `Fundamentals.Test`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: If they are 2 different project then you will have to include the dll. have you done that.

Comment: yes got it  i missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Fundamentals.Test` project needs to refer to the `Fundamentals` project.

Just right click on the `References` node of the `Fundamentals.Test` project and select [`Add Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) from the right click menu.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a *using* directive is not enough, first you need to add a reference to your assembly from your test project.Then include the namespace (optional) or use the fully-qualified name of the type.

You can refer to this documentation if you don't know how to add a reference to a different assembly from your project:

- [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If they are two different project then you will have to include the `dll` in other project. have you done that?

I mean have you, added the reference of the `fundamentals` project to `fundamentals.test` by clicking on `reference` folder and then click `add reference`. You can directly select the dll from `projects` tab.